# How to get the response stream on a non 201 status code

Tags: c#, http, response, webrequest

I'm having some problem's grabbing a response stream from a request that returning status code 422.

```
HttpWebResponse objResponse = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse();
```

The wr.GetResponse throws an webexception because the status code isnt 201.
So i can never get the response stream from the remote server. But it does return important information in the ResponseStream.

So my question is how to retrieve the ResponseStream on a request that doesnt return 201 but still returns data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WebException that is thrown contains a reference to the response from which you can get the response steam.

```
catch(WebException ex)
{
     ex.Response.GetResponseStream();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use TcpClient and send the HTTP Request manually. It's a pretty simple request format.

Comment: Guess that could be a solution. But isnt there a way to use HttpWebResponse/HttpWebRequest

Comment: I guess you could test the StatusCode and then look in the Headers collection to see what header info the server returned you

Comment: Well yes guess thats possible. But the thing is that it returns data in the ResponseBody (ResponseStream). So i cant reach that data when looking at the headers